# Put something under it for support

Tags: word-usage

A person was writing on a sheet of paper,  so he asked for a notebook to put under it.

> Can I get something to put under it for support?
>
> Can I get something to prop under this page?
>
> Can I get something to prop this (page) up?

Is the use of "support" natural here?  What do you think?

Comment: I've never heard anyone in the US say it like that.

Comment: _"Can I please have a notebook on which to rest this?"_ might be a better way of asking.

Comment: Nobody would normally provide a rationale for such a request. They would simply say, "Can I get a notebook?" or "Would you have a notebook?" The addition of any reason behind the request is odd. (If they really did want to provide a reason, it's also doubtful they'd limit the request to a just notebook. They'd likely ask for something like  *a book, a binder, a notebook, or something else* to put under the paper.)

Comment: @JasonBassford does "prop up" work? **Can I get something to prop up this sheet of paper?** (I think it doesn't work..) And what about: "**Can I get something to put under this (page) for support"**? (I know in reality one might just ask for anything (Like: "Can I get a book" because you know what you'd do with it, but suppose you don't specify the book but just ask for anything that you can put under the book so that you can write properly on the sheet of paper..), but I want to know how the reason might be specified if any case it is.,)

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish : in the UK I might naturally say *"Have you got anything I can **lean on**?"*.  It's not perfect but, in context, I reckon most people here would understand you.